# App is not making api calls even after adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Tags: android, react-native

React-native version=0.65.1

While testing after running the app using npx react-native run-android app is working fine but when i tested after building .apk it is not making any calls not even the login api(http://.....).

I tried again after adding  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in manifest but  no change.

Comment: in Manifest file, Internet permission should be there.

Comment: yes, I'm providing internet permission like this     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me
"react-test-renderer": "17.0.2" downgraded to
"react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
after seeing the [image: logCat]
use logCat to see release version logs.